# BeautifulSoup4: select elements where attributes are not equal to x

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'd like to do something like this:

```
soup.find_all('td', attrs!={"class":"foo"})
```

I want to find all td that do not have the class of foo.

Obviously the above doesn't work, what does?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` really makes the "soup" beautiful and easy to work with.

You [can pass a function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) in the attribute value:

```
soup.find_all('td', class_=lambda x: x != 'foo')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """
... <tr>
...     <td>1</td>
...     <td class="foo">2</td>
...     <td class="bar">3</td>
... </tr>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> for element in soup.find_all('td', class_=lambda x: x != 'foo'):
...     print element.text
... 
1
3
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a method `.select()` which allows you to pass CSS selectors as a string:

```py
soup.select('td:not(.foo)')
```

The above code will return all `<td>` tags which are not of the class `foo`.