# How can I __scrap__ the 2nd <a> tag's link with BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the html code to **scrape** from

```
<div class="archive-pagination pagination">
<ul>
<li class="active" >
<a href="https://random.com/" aria-label="Current page" aria-current="page">1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://google.com/">2</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking for the next page number in the pagination. For this I would go with this approach:

```
soup.find('div', class_='pagination').find_all('a', attrs={'aria-label':None})
```

This will list out the a tags that are not `Current page`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```py
soup.select('div.active-pagination a')[1]['href']
```

What it does? Select all "a" tags in div with class active-pagination, then take the second one. If you want to select all "a" tags that don't have `aria-label` property, then see [BeautifulSoup4: select elements where attributes are not equal to x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798062/beautifulsoup4-select-elements-where-attributes-are-not-equal-to-x)